# Difference between a/img/..//text() and a//text()

Tags: xpath, scrapy, lxml, lxml.html

I'm working with Scrapy and lxml trees to sort out html trees.

I noticed that there is difference between these two xpath expressions. I was under the impression that they were interchangeable. Could someone please explain me the difference?

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/a/img/..//text()').extract()

response.xpath('/html/body/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/a//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `a/img/..//text()` and `a//text()` is that the first will return you text nodes *ONLY* from `a` elements with `img` elements as children, whereas the second will return text nodes from `a` elements irrespective of whether they have `img` elements as children.

Put another way, `a/img/..//text()` could equally be written `a[img]//text()`; compare this with `a//text()`.